# Horizontally center absolutely positioned image inside div without horizontal scroll bars showing up (in mobile too)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this image in the div without the horizontal scroll bars showing up. I need the image to be absolutely positioned within the div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/512t9L6b/

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://iqtell.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/James-Bond.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Edit: Tried `html { overflow-x:hidden }` as suggested but it still scrolls horizontally in mobile.

Comment: you have too apply it to the main div too, not only html for mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html {
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

will remove the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Just tried this but it looks like it still scrolls horizontally on mobile.

Comment: Never mind, created a site wrapper inside the body and applied `overflow-x:hidden` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/3au44f27/

CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Or just center horizontally

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/0cjyfwq8/

CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```